# Why is "..." required before a function call that is being passed as an expression inside map function in React with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So, I am trying to render a list of items, and want to style the background depending on a certain prop's value.

I opted to use the `.map` function.

The code look like this:

```
itemCards.map((item) => 
  <div key= {item.id} className={'list_card'} {getCardColor(item)}>
```

The issue here is that Typescript is insisting I put the the spread operator (...) before the function call of `getColorCard`.

So it should look like this:

```
itemCards.map((item) => 
  <div key= {item.id} className={'list_card'} {...getCardColor(item)}>
```

and the function `getCardColor` look like this:

```
function getCardColor(item: ItemCard): React.CSSProperties {
    if(item.priority === null){
        return ({background:"red"})
    }
    return ({background:"black"})
}
```

It works.

My question would be why do I need a spread operator before the function call in my case?

Sorry if this was asked before, but I don't how to search for it on Google.

Edit: I put in what getCardColor returns

Comment: React thinks you're trying to add props to your `div` element. Why are you calling a method within the div opening tag??

Comment: I assume `getCardColor` returns an actual value in your real code? What you've included in the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: That's the wrong way to log something from the template. You realize you're calling a rendering function that never returns anything to be rendered? Or is the function actually returning attributes?

Comment: @DBS @JuanMendes  My `getCardColor` is like that :

`function getCardColor(item: ItemCard): React.CSSProperties {
    if(item.priority === null){
        return ({background:"red"})
    }
    return ({background:"black"})
}`

Answer (score 1):

JSX syntax essentially converts to calling a function and passing it an argument which is an object made up of the props and their values.

```
 <Func foo="bar" />
```

is roughly the same as:

```
 const props = { foo: "bar" };
 Func(props);
```

---

If you have an object with some props and values already, then you can use the spread operator to combine two objects.

```
 <Func foo="bar" a={1} />

 const moreProps = { a: 1 };
 const props = { foo: "bar", ...moreProps };
 Func(props);
```

---

You can do the spreading inside the JSX:

```
 <Func foo="bar" {...moreProps} />
```

But you can't just slap in a value by itself like that.

---

```
 const props = { "a value" };
```

That's an error in JS.

---

So you have to spread the return value of the function.

---

However, your function returns `undefined` so putting it in the middle of JSX like that is nonsensical in the first place.